# How can I add selectable suggestion list to UISearch Bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5, uisearchbar

I am a new to iOS development. I am trying to create a word suggestion list to UISearch Bar in IOS SDK 4.3  for iPhone.

Initially if the user taps on a UISearch field it will move to up on the screen and pop up the blank list while user starts to type a search key word it will list down the suggestions under UISearch bar according to search key word. [An example is Google search.]. The suggestion of the list, which comes from the return of web services.

It is a bit difficult to understand how should I create and appear a table view with the suggestions on top of existing screen while moving upto top of the UISearch bar and how should I move the search bar into top of the screen and set into previous place according to user interaction while I hide the suggestion table view.

Thanks..

Comment: If you mean dynamic searching, then simply implementing the UISearchBar will already do that as far as I remember...So I think you don't really need to do anything special in this case (unless I magically did some intense coding in my old projects without realizing it). Try it. It will automatically give you suggestions base on what you have in the list. Of course if you want to suggest the users to search for something that's NOT already on the list then you will have to do more work (but there's no point...or is there? 'Cause there won't be any search result for a search like that)